# Pass user input value from class to class on Java

Tags: java, class

I am working on the parking ticket simulator of the starting out with Java book, so the idea is to ask the user to input the officer's name, officer's badge number and some other other information, I have that information in the class `ParkingCarSimulator` class located on `ParkingCarSimulator.java`,

All of that is working fine, now in class called `PoliceOfficer` located in `PoliceOfficer.java` file, I would like to know if I can access the user input from the main method in the `ParkingCarSimulator` into the `PoliceOfficer` class.

Any ideas will be appreciated, here is the code I have:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ParkingCarSimulator {
    
    public static void main(String[] arsg)
    {
        
        String officerName, Make, carModel, carColor, carLicense;
        int badgeNumber, minOnCar, minPurchased;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the officer's name");
        officerName = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the officer's badge number");
        badgeNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the car's make");
        Make = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the car's model");
        carModel = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the car's color");
        carColor = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the car's liscence number");
        carLicense = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter minutes on car");
        minOnCar = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of minutes purchased");
        minPurchased = keyboard.nextInt();
        
    }

}
```

Here is PoliceOfficer.java

```java
public class PoliceOfficer
{
    String policeName = ParkingCarSimulator.officerName;(this throws an error)
}
```

Comment: What errors if thrown ? Please [edit] your post and add the stacktrace

Comment: Any variables defined in a *method* are deemed *local* and are not accessible anywhere outside the method.

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

To create a `PoliceOfficer`, you need to give it a `constructor` then instanciate it in the main code

```
public class PoliceOfficer{
    String policeName;
    int badgeNumber;

    public PoliceOfficer(String policeName, int badgeNumber){
        this.policeName = policeName;
        this.badgeNumber = badgeNumber;
    }
}
```

use

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter the officer's name");
    String  officerName = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the officer's badge number");
    int  badgeNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
    
    PoliceOfficer po = new PoliceOfficer(officerName, badgeNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, it stills throws an error in the following: ```PoliceOfficer po = PoliceOfficer(officerName, badgeNumber);``` it says = PoliceOfficer The method PoliceOfficer(String, int) is undefined for the type ParkingCarSimulator

Comment: @TomRonaldo I forgot the `new` before `PoliceOfficer` look the edit. Also you may import `PoliceOfficer` in ParkingCarSimulator  file